Background service current location error in Flutter
I am trying to access currentlocation through background service using workmanager package but it didnot return position. Althought when accessing currentlocation through onpressed it worked fine. What is the solution?
Can someone help me to fetch user current location through background process

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
